# How do I see if a process is running in 32-bit or 64-bit mode in the Windows 8/10 Task Manager?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit, task-manager

Previously, I would look in Task Manager for a `*32` next to the process name in Task Manager to tell what platform the process is running on:

[image]

---

However, in Windows 8 and 10 (on the details tab) this is not present:

[image]

---

How can I see, in Task Manager, if my processes are running as 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: Task manager in my Windows 8/10 has always displayed `(32 bit)` beside the app names, no changes is required to see the platform http://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Windows-10-task-manager-file-run.png

Comment: You are looking at different tabs...within task manager

Comment: @Ramhound True, but as the "details" tab is closer to the functionality of the earlier Windows "processes" tab, this is what I prefer to use for all the details to be displayed (as the name implies).

Answer (score 35):

1. Right click on the column headers and click `Select columns`

[image]

2. Check `Platform`

[image]

3. Drag the new column where you want

[image]

Comment: switch to Processes tab and you'll see the platform in the app name

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Definitely a fair point - My preference is the Details tab as it's a lot more comprehensive and uses less space, but I didn't specify that in the question. Thanks though, you're right, it's definitely there in the other tab.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I see, in Task Manager, if my processes are running as 32-bit or 64-bit?

You can use an alternative Task Manager, for example [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) (free, open source, can replace Task Manager and there is a portable version).

**Bits** can be added as a column to the normal detailed "Process" display:

[image]